# Insufficient space error on Intel Galileo running yocto

Tags: node.js, iot, yocto, intel-galileo

I want to install a new node library with npm on my Intel Galileo Gen 2 board running yocto (iot-devkit-1.5-i586-galileo). This has worked perfectly a couple of times before, however I have come to a point where npm tells me that I do not have sufficient space on my system which I can't really believe as I am using a 8GB SD card and yocto only takes up 1.3GB.

When I run npm install geoip-lite I get the following error:
[image: ERROR on npm install]

When I run df -h I get the following:
[image: System partitions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yocto won't create a larger rootfs unless you tell it to (you can imagine someone with a 2GB SD card would be annoyed if the image was 4GB for no apparent reason).

You should probably use `IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "1048576"` in your image recipe to set the amount of free space you want in Kbytes, but please read the [IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE) as well for the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your rootfs is full (100% used). npm install writes to the rootfs, so the problem is clear. So either remove unnecessary bits from the rootfs or increase the rootfs size.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really prefer `IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE =` as this will increase the download size of the file (`*.sdcard *.rootfs`) by a big chunk given that I compile the Image in Amazon EC2.

What I usually do is, compress the rootfs to tar ball and download to local.

In my SD Card, I set up 2 partitions using `fdisk` , one is for kernel and the other is for Rootfs. Use `dd command` for the `uboot`, put the Kernel `.dtb` and `.bin` into the first partition and just extract the `rootfs` tarball into the second parition.

Doing this way, I make sure that I use every single space in the SD Card. And, it is easier for me to change the rootfs if I need to.